# Integrate Swagger-generated models into personal test framework

Tags: java, maven, swagger

I have a self-developed Java project (Maven-built), which is created for testing an API. Inside there are manually created POJO-models, which I use to get data from server's responses inside tests.

Now we decided to integrate Swagger. My, as QA, point of interest here the Swagger json to be the one and only "source of truth" for both developers and API tests. So I decided the java models must be generated dynamically for in-test usage. I managed to generate models, but it seems swagger-codegen-cli creates the whole new Java project. I can of course just set -o to put generated sources inside my java-api-tests project, but it seems it is the wrong way to do it and my goal is reached more correctly in a different way.

Have you ever been using swagger for such purposes?

Comment: After todays researching I found there IS a way to generate only needed java classes from swagger.json (only models for example), but files generated appear in src/main/java , while all my project is in src/test/java. Moving the project to main brakes Maven convention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is quite common.  Consider the swagger-codegen-maven-plugin to write files, from your swagger definition, to the generated-files folder.  You can then use those for your tests, etc., and the swagger definition will always be the source of truth.

You can even consider pulling the swagger definition down using wget from a github repo or other.  You don't really want to write them to the `src/main` folder, you can either let them live in the `generated-files` or `src/gen/java`.

The codegen allows you to specify what you want to generate, avoiding the pom.xml, etc.

Comment: Thanks for a reply and more integration ideas. Today I will try to implement it with maven plugin and then will write back

Comment: Works great with swagger-codegen-maven-plugin! Thanks again